# Issue with IBOutlets in ViewController

Tags: swift, xib, swift3, xcode8, iboutlet

When I load View Controller from xib with table view within, I receive an error in log window that says:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This exception occurs when there are no IBOutlet, that have connection in IB, but all my connections have an appropriate variables.
If I break the connection with tableView Outlet, this issue disappears.
Help me, please. I think it's a bug of compilation. In debugger I found out that the loadView method can't perform [variables before execution of loadView method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ngZ2.png) [All my connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwed1.png)

Comment: XIB delete and make again.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a phantom connection, that means you might have a button with an IB Action that does not exist or the name of the button has been changed later on. You can solve this problem by going into the Main.storyboard and **right click on the file controller(the yellow icon on the top left) and delete the action with a yellow flag (warning on it)** 
Hope it works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

@Purteeek gave a very good answer. Another thing I would add is that you may have changed the class from ViewController to something else in the Interface Builder, which could cause you issues. But very likely Purteek is right; just wanted to add this in case that didn't work :-)